# Does this sequence converge to the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, bounded and integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. Further take the sequence $(q_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\{ q_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{Q}.$

Does then $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(q_i) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \, dx $$ hold?

Edit: I added that $f$ has to be integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why should that integral exist? Did you want to work on $[0,1]$ or something?

Comment: Riemann sums are for definite integrals, also called Riemann integrals. You have above an indefinite integral.

Comment: The *set* $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite cardinality, which you blithely take as $N$. You'll have to do *serious* explaining to do here. True, the sum looks like a Riemann sum, but sum over *all* rationals?

Comment: @zhw Sorry I forgot to mention that $f$ should be integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. I assume that the integral exists.

Comment: @vonbrand did you oversee my limit symbol? The set $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorph to $\mathbb{N}$ so I think its fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(x) = 1, x\in [0,1], f = 0$ elsewhere. (I know this $f$ is not continuous, but let's allow it into the game for now.) Arrange the enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ so that $q_{n} \in [0,1]$ for odd $n$ and and $q_n \not \in [0,1]$ for even $n.$ What is the value of

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(q_n)$$

for even $N?$

Comment: Okay. After seeing this example, I guess there are even many continuous, bounded, indefinite integrable functions $f$ where $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(q_i)$ does not even converge at all.

Comment: Right, with the function in my example you should be able enumerate $\mathbb Q$ so that the sequence of sums is even dense in $[0,1].$

Answer (score 2):

Let f(x) = 1 for all x. Then the left hand side is equal to 1, but the right hand side is infinite.

Comment: No, the right hand side is 1.

Comment: Well it's not even clear what is intended at this point.

Comment: I am assuming the integral was over the entire domain.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. But good catch :D.